# NLog issue writing object to database using WCF C#.NET

Tags: c#, nlog

I'm currently having a problem writing a XML value to a database table using NLog. I'm using WCF and C#

I have a request XML object that i'm writing to the database, and if i use the built in "message" object as follows, it works:

NLog.Config

```
<parameter name="@message" layout="${message}" />
```

Code behind:

```
logger.Debug("{@value1}", new { request1 = request});
```

But if i try and write it to another field, for example:

```xml
<parameter name="@Request" layout="${event-properties:value1}" />
```

It doesn't write the value of the object to the table, but:

"MyServices.Types.Request"

Request type is:

```
namespace MyServices.Types
{
    [DataContract]
    public class Request
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string MessageHeader { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public int EventType { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string Identification { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public DateTime VisitDate { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Is there a reason for this? The "Message" property seems to work correctly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NLog 4.6 allows you to render XML into the DatabaseTarget:

```
<parameter name="@Request" DbType="SqlDbType.Xml">
   <layout type="xmllayout" includeAllProperties="true" />
</parameter>
```

NLog 4.6 also allows you set the DbType for the parameter. See aslo https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/XmlLayout

Answer (score 4):

(this is an answer for an older NLog version. For the latest, see Rolf's answer)

Even with structured logging, the event properties aren't converted to a structured format - it's using a `ToString`

Currently JSON serialize is only supported, not XML

```xml
<parameter name="@Request" layout="${event-properties:value1:format=@}" />
```

See [${event-properties} docs](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/All-Event-Properties-Layout-Renderer) for more options and examples

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. I've tried both examples above but still getting the same output unfortunately. "MyServices.Types.Request".

Comment: can you try logging it to a file? Also maybe it's useful to show us the type MyServices.Types.Request

Comment: same when i log to a file. I've updated the question with the type definition

Comment: It was indeed wrong. Updated the answer, but only JSON is support for now